# duplicity crashes in deja-dup

Tags: openssl, duplicity

I use Ubuntu 22.04 with all packages up-to-date

Hit by "Could not understand duplicity version." in Deja-dup, I checked duplicity

```
[xavier@imladris ~]$ duplicity --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 42, in <module>
    from duplicity.dup_main import main
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/duplicity/dup_main.py", line 37, in <module>
    import fasteners
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/fasteners/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from fasteners.lock import locked  # noqa
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/fasteners/lock.py", line 31, in <module>
    import eventlet
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/eventlet/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from eventlet import convenience
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/eventlet/convenience.py", line 7, in <module>
    from eventlet.green import socket
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/eventlet/green/socket.py", line 4, in <module>
    __import__('eventlet.green._socket_nodns')
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/eventlet/green/_socket_nodns.py", line 11, in <module>
    from eventlet import greenio
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/eventlet/greenio/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from eventlet.greenio.base import *  # noqa
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/eventlet/greenio/base.py", line 471, in <module>
    from OpenSSL import SSL
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/OpenSSL/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from OpenSSL import crypto, SSL
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/OpenSSL/crypto.py", line 3279, in <module>
    _lib.OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms()
AttributeError: module 'lib' has no attribute 'OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms'
```

An idea how to fix this ? I already reinstall python3-cryptography with no success

Thanks, cheers

Xavier

Comment: Did you make changes or install a different version of Python on the OS.

Comment: No, everything if from Ubuntu

Comment: Consider filling a bug report.

Answer (score 1):

reads like there is a bug in python module pyOpenSSL. upgrading that to v22.1.0 or later is supposed to fix it.

see
https://levelup.gitconnected.com/fix-attributeerror-module-lib-has-no-attribute-openssl-521a35d83769

Answer (score 0):

Tried to solve by `sudo dpkg -r --force-depends python3-cryptography` then
`sudo python3 -m pip install  "cryptography<40.0"` as indicated on duplicty github issues

It didn't fix the problem, so I deinstalled with `pip remove`, then `sudo apt --fix-broken install` in order to reinstall python3-cryptography

Everything runs fine now, I don't really understand why...

Comment: probably just a hickup in updating. usually dependencies make sure these incompatibilities do not occur. also be aware that pip dependencies exist in parallel to you system python packages maintained with dpkg/apt.